# Is it possible to delete an element off of a canvas using javascript without clearing the whole canvas?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

What I would like to do is draw a circle on a canvas and then when a function is called delete the previous circle and draw a new one. Is this possible without having to redraw the whole canvas?

Take the code below for example

```
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(95, 50, 40, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
ctx.stroke();
```

Comment: You have to clear the context and next you redraw everything except the circle.

Answer (score 0):

A canvas is a collection of pixels (it's exactly like an image, however it's computed from code instead of being just loaded from file).

The only way to remove the old circle and draw the new one (if you want pixel perfect result) is repainting everything with the circle in the new position.

A possible solution could be using three distinct `canvas` elements layered one on top of the other:

1. whatever is **behind** the changing parts
2. the changing parts
3. whatever is **covering** the changing parts

1 and 3 can be kept fixed, you need to redraw only the second canvas.

Comment: This would work perfectly however is it possible to make the background of the top canvas transparent?

Comment: @ZaneSmit: a canvas is by default all transparent. For every pixel you have 4 bytes: r, g, b and alpha. If you draw objects on a canvas the parts you never draw to are see-trough (alpha=0)